# How to get TenantID of the caller in Microsoft Bot Framework v4 when I only have the TurnContext?

Tags: typescript, botframework

We are new to the Microsoft Bot Framework and we are using Typescript and V4 of the BotFramework.

We are looking for a way to get the (caller) tenantId.

We keep getting undefined for the tenantId, where the channelId is properly filled.

```
this.onMessage(async (turnContext, next) => {
        props.channelId = turnContext.activity.channelId;
        
        const allUsefulData = Array<string>(5);
        console.log("#TenantID:" + turnContext.activity.conversation.tenantId);
        console.log(turnContext.activity.channelId);
```

Returns (when used in Sharepoint)

> #TenantID:undefined
>
> directline

or (when used in Teams)

> #TenantID:undefined
>
> msteams

Should we configure something extra ?

Comment: Ran a quick test with c# sample and Teams, and I received a GUID. tenantId in WebChat is null, which is probably expected, and I'm not sure if it can be set. I'll see what more I can find out.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get Tenant ID in Teams in Typescript. What exact version of the Bot SDK are you using?

For Webchat, I believe you will have to get the Tenant ID, then put that in ChannelData. Webchat has no idea about a tenant, because it could be running anywhere (any web server). See [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/b.piggyback-on-outgoing-activities) for how to send data in ChannelData. Assuming you are using SPFx, this should be pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

Typical 'magic fingers' event occured.
After a fresh start with the same code (different developer), we now DO get the tenantId.
Thanks @Dana V for the quick reply